# Grails 3 - Resource Plugin

Tags: javascript, css, grails-3.0, grails-2.2

i would like to ask you, if you know something about great Grails plugin (https://grails.org/plugin/resources) for new Grails 3 (working with 3.0.4). This plugin allow to create resource (JS, CSS ...) bundles, dependencies etc. ...

It would be great to have it in Grails 3 or something similiar. Can i use it with new Grails ?

In "build.gradle" can be this plugin included (for runtime) but question is where to put configuration of bundles. Example :

```
modules = {
   core {
      dependsOn 'jquery, utils'
```

Thank you very much !

Answer (score -1):

This works for me:

```
<asset:stylesheet src="application.css"/>
<asset:javascript src="application.js"/>
<asset:javascript src="boo.js"/>
<asset:javascript src="jquery-ui.js"/>
<g:layoutHead/>
```

Comment: I am using grails 3.0.9 by the way.

Comment: Asset-pipeline does not (appear to) bundle intelligently and will put multiple copies of resource files on your page if you use multiple <asset> tags of the same type.